# .htaccess rewrite for Wordpress not working at all. Trying to pass a GET parameter

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a wordpress website and I am trying to pass a get parameter in the URL.

I want `website.com/casino-review/example-casino` to actually be processed as `website.com/casino-review/?casino=example-casino`.

Everything I'm trying seems to have no effect whatsoever.

For example I tried the simple (just for troubleshooting purposes):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule /casino-review/golden-nugget /casino-review/?casino=golden-nugget
</IfModule>
```

When I try to access `/casino-review/golden-nugget` I get a 404 rather than having the GET passed.
I've tried many combinations and nothing seems to work.

Feels like I'm missing something, perhaps the fact that Wordpress is already rewriting the URLs and it's somehow conflicting with what I'm doing.

Any advice?
Thank you

Comment: Of course WP does its own rewrites already, at least if you have any form of “pretty” URLs enabled. It is not really clear here, what you are trying to achieve - who or what is supposed to handle the request for `/casino-review/`, is that a page you created in WP, do you have that mapped to a script of your own? Is this a taxonomy or custom post type?

Comment: I have a large mysql casino database, and rather than create individual pages for all the casinos, I decided to create a single casino-review page. This casino-review pages takes the GET variable from the URL and pulls the casino data from the database (e.g. name, star rating, bonus, etc).

Right now, when I access `website.com/casino-review/?casino=example`, the page works perfectly. So I just need `website.com/casino-review/example` to actually go to `?casino=example`, but I can't seem to do it

Comment: I think this should work: `RewriteRule ^casino-review/([^/]+)/?$ casino-review/casino=$1`

But it's not working. In fact nothing I'm doing seems to work or produce any changes.

Comment: That’s missing the question mark, to start the query string - `casino-review/?casino=$1`. If it still doesn’t work, then please show where exactly you placed this; should come before the general WP rewrite that sends everything to the index.php

Comment: The missing ? was just a typo. I placed it before, between, after with various flags and combos and nothing is working. I'll share my actual .htaccess

Comment: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=b0572a76-0037-57d4-be3f-7c67906ab9fc

Comment: It shows _“The new url is `https://example.com/casino-review/?casino=golden-nugget`”_ in multiple places there, so in theory, this should work. (`RewriteRule ^^casino-review/…` with the double `^^` still a typo though, I suppose.) And even when that re-written URL is feed in to the whole process a second time, it stays as it is.

Comment: Guess WP might be messing this up later somehow, perhaps? Maybe try and edit the index.php, to make a debug output of $_SERVER, and have it die afterwards - and then test what happens when you call `/casino-review/?casino=golden-nugget`. If that doesn’t 404, and shows the expected values for request URI and query string inside the $_SERVER values, that would point to WP doing something wrong with it afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. Will try that. Also worth a quick try to just disable all plugins. Will do that and get back to you later. Thanks for the help